# Running windows make command fails

Tags: windows, makefile, build

I have just started working on a project in windows environment. The project is compiled and build using make command which compiles and generates the executables. It is a C# project. However, when I run the make command to build, I get the following error --  E:\GJoaquin\depot\sim\joaquin>make

> was unexpected at this time.
>   "Error: "WORKSTATION_VERSION not defined. Please define in test test bora/publi
>   /vm_version.h.""
>   was unexpected at this time.
>   was unexpected at this time.
>   ! was unexpected at this time.
>   make: *** [default] Error 255

I am not very knowledgeable on make files. Not sure which make file and which line in that make file might be causing the problem. Do you have any idea on how to debug this?

Comment: > was unexpected at this time,,this is what make is saying

Comment: There must be a makefile (`Makefile`, `makefile`?) in `E:\GJoaquin\depot\sim\joaquin` that `make` finds. Posting that would be good start.